# Chat along with another data sending in socket programming android

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm developing a project where client sends screenshots of its activity to server where the bitmap is converted to string.For me it works well.I would like to add a chat between client and server in this project.How can I achieve this?Any kind of help is accepted.

Client Code

```
   public class Client2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     public static String dstAddress;
int dstPort;
String response= new String() ;
String msg_server=new String();
Context context;
   public static   ArrayList<Bitmap>ss=new ArrayList<>();
   public static Socket socket;
Client2(Context ic,String addr, int port,String msg) {
    context=ic;
    dstAddress = addr;
    dstPort = port;
    msg_server=msg;

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    socket = null;
  ObjectOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
  ObjectInputStream dataInputStream = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
        dataOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                socket.getOutputStream());
        dataInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        if(msg_server != null){
            dataOutputStream.writeObject(msg_server);
            dataOutputStream.flush();

        }

        response = (String) dataInputStream.readObject();



    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {  socket.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataInputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Server Code

```
public class Server extends Thread{

ServerSocket serverSocket;
Viewer activity;
static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
int count = 0;
int sc=0;
Bitmap bmviewer;
String msgtoclient,msgfromclient;
ArrayList<Bitmap>ser=new ArrayList<>();
public  Server(Activity context,String msg )
 {
activity= (Viewer) context;
msgtoclient=msg;
 }
@Override
public void run() {
    Socket socket = null;
    ObjectInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    ObjectOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

    try {
       // serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(); // <-- create an unbound socket first
        serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(SocketServerPORT));// serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Viewer.demo.setText("Port No: "
                        + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
            }
        });

        while (true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            dataInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                    socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());


            String messageFromClient = new String();
            //If no message sent from client, this code will block the program


            messageFromClient = (String) dataInputStream.readObject();


            count++;

            bmviewer = (stringtobitmap(messageFromClient));

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Viewer.demo.setText(message);
                    sc++;
                    saveimage(bmviewer, sc);
                    // Viewer.images.setImageBitmap(bmviewer);
                    Viewer.imageGallery.addView(getImageView(bmviewer));


                }
            });
      if (msgtoclient.equals("")){
              String reply="received";
                dataOutputStream.writeObject(reply);
                dataOutputStream.flush();}
            else {
            dataOutputStream.writeObject(msgtoclient);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            }



        }
    }catch(EOFException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        final String errMsg = e.toString();
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Snackbar snackbar=Snackbar.make(Viewer.relativeLayout,errMsg,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        });
    }   catch(IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        final String errMsg = e.toString();
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Snackbar snackbar=Snackbar.make(Viewer.relativeLayout,errMsg,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        });

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataInputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
private View getImageView(Bitmap image) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(activity);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    return imageView;
}
private void saveimage(Bitmap bmp,int c) {
    sc=c;
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/screenshare_viewer");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    //Random generator = new Random();
   // int n = 10000;
   // n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+sc +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Bitmap stringtobitmap(String message) {
    try{
        byte [] encodeByte= Base64.decode(message,Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,      encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}


}
```

Comment: o_O Please tell us more about the application of yours? You must be omitting something or it's the most roundabout way of implementation I've heard about.

Comment: There exists a client activity which takes screenshot which is converted to string and send to server.Server decodes the string to bitmap and sets to imageview and servers sends an acknowledgement in return.I want to add a chat between client and server to this project.How can I implement that

Comment: `where client sends screenshots of its activity to server where the bitmap is converted to string.`. Not at all. You dont even know what your code does. The client sends a string to the server to begin with. And the server handles this string and tries to make a bitmap out of it if we have to believe the function name.

Comment: `ObjectInputStream dataInputStream = null;`. Please dont call an ObjectInputStream a data input stream. You write unreadable code doing so.